# How to configure a fallback CACHE_TYPE in flask-cache?

Tags: python, flask, flask-cache

I am having great speed up using [flask-cache](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/) configured to work with a redis-server instance. However, if the redis-server becomes unavailable I get an error message:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError
ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

Since chaching is just to increase performance I would like to configure a fallback (slower) `CACHE_TYPE` (e.g., `simple`) to deal with redis-server problems without affecting flask functionalities. If not possible I hope to dinamically-programmatically disable the cache to prevent any flask error.

**EDIT**

I tried to solve the problem on my own: https://github.com/paolinux79/flask-cache

Comment: Why not think of the other options?  Why not establish a redis cluster to prevent failure?  Ideally, you would want to remove any single-point-of-failures.  http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Comment: Hey Carlos, I think that redis is a great nosql ultrafast db but redis-cluster is, imho, far away from being a real cluster (like riak for example).